# Error While creating a bucket through cbq shell in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

When I execute the following command to create a bucket in couchbase server.

```
cbq.exe> bucket-create -c 127.0.0.1:8091 -u Administrator -p password --bucket=test_bucket --bucket-type=couchbase --bucket-port=11222 --bucket-ramsize=200 --bucket-replica=1 --wait;
```

**Error output:**

```
{
    "requestID": "d88894ad-085d-44c7-b600-3917bc254035",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 3000,
            **"msg": "syntax error - at bucket"**
        }
    ],
    "status": "fatal",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "1.0001ms",
        "executionTime": "1.0001ms",
        "resultCount": 0,
        "resultSize": 0,
        "errorCount": 1
    }
}
```

Could some body tell me what is wrong in my command?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using cbq which is for running N1QL queries.

Perhaps you meant couchbase-cli instead.

```
$ /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli bucket-create -c 127.0.0.1:8091 
-u Administrator -p password --bucket=test_bucket --bucket-type=couchbase
--bucket-port=11222 --bucket-ramsize=100 --bucket-replica=1 --wait
...SUCCESS: bucket-create
```